# Latest FileDialog Class path

Tags: file-upload, swt, eclipse-rap

I need to enable user to load data into app via csv. I *can* use FileUpload class, but I feel FileDialog is more likely the future direction of RAP releases as a lot has progressed with File Loader/Dialog (and the entire Utility helper re-write).

Per latest RAP forum reference:

https://eclipse.org/rap/noteworthy/3.0/ states

> The FileDialog is located in the org.eclipse.rap.filedialog bundle in
>   the RAP target platform

Yet I see no corresponding path in the target platform download.

[image]

I have installed latest updates from distribution url through my IDE. This was with RapTools 3.1.2 2016/11/xx(stable build), and I have now tried pulling latest nightly build (marked 3.1.2 2017/02/15).

---

Perhaps I am simply having trouble following the latest events around the Classes?

Answer (score 0):

The description you quote says the org.eclipse.rap.filedialog **bundle**.

Bundle here is the OSGi term for a separate plugin. There is a `org.eclipse.rap.filedialog_xxxxx.jar` in the RAP download / update site containing this code.